# UEFI Bios and SEC Phase

Tags: security, boot, bios, uefi, tpm

My bios knowledge it's pretty base but everytime that I read some documents about UEFI and I don't understand why the SEC phase is the Root of trust in UEFI bios procedures.

The SEC phase performs validation of PEI but I don't understand who or in wich way the SEC phase is authenticated and validated. Can someone give me some explaination ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When CPU starts it executes only a few very specific instructions at a very specific address. Nothing is initialized yet, not south/north bridge, not memory itself (dram), so there is simply not enough resources to start any code but sec. And sec initializes it all. Only then you have enough resources to execute code.

Another thing. In order to update the UEFI firmware (BIOS) from the OS or UEFI shell the capsule has to be signed. So no tempering on this phase ether.

You can rip out the chip and reprogram it with your tempered firmware but that is another story and writing your own bios is not a trivial task.

So, all that said, that's why Sec Phase is ROT.

Comment: Forgot to clarify: those instructions loads and executes sec in cpu's cash. Then sec initializes dram and other crap. ;)

Comment: So, the sec is the root of trust only because it's hard to replace the bios chip.

Comment: Theoretically yes! Not the chip - firmware inside. Theoretically there is no such thing as security! Even RSA2056 can be cracked in 100+ years! If hacker can get access to the source code of the BIOS for that particular system, modify it and then re flush the targeted machine there is no way you can protect it. But practically, in the real word, it is highly unlikely for a hacker or even for a group of hackers to completely rewrite the entire BIOS. There is some security issues and concerns even on the manufacturer floor how to establish the chain of trust when the motherboard is assembled.

Comment: Well my board is a little bit different and there is an fpga between cpu and bios flash that perform an hmac-sha1 authentication of the bios. But I get your point.

Comment: Actually I think on some cup's there is a section of firmware, a small RISC processor which is secure (difficult to reverse engineer) which executes out of the firmware. Also there are fuses in this processor which the vendor can set once, probably to sign the that portion of firmware which validates the first firmware code or all the firmware on the bios. So if you ran your own sec on the spi eeprom it would notice and possiblyonly operate in a limited mode. Provided the vendor has chosen to utilize such functionality.